# Lock to fit around Big Apple tyres (28x2.35)

Tags: tire, lock

I have a new bike on the way which has Big Apple tyres (28x2.35), which will be my first experience with tyres this big. I'll also be installing fenders.

I'm wondering if my Kryptonite Evo Mini-5 is going to fit around the rim/tyre/fender (Sheldon Brown-style), and if not, is there a Kryptonite U-lock which will?

Comment: Why don't you just try it?  Do you not yet have the bike in your possession ?

Comment: Correct, the bike is not yet in my possession. Without going into the tedious details, if I need a new lock it's best for me to buy it along with the bike and have them all shipped together, hence the question.

Answer (score 4):

I'd guess the big apple will make it tight depending on what you lock to.

Certainly the long shackle variants or standard shackle variants will fit around this. I have a Kryptonite New York Lock in a long shackle variant can fit around pretty much anything.

When you get the bike, you can easily measure the width the lock needs to have along with the length of the shackle to lock around what you need to lock to. I carry one New York Lock Long Shackle and 1 Fahgettaboutit so that I can lock in tighter places (and lock both the front and rear wheels with U-locks). I'd think even if the mini isn't suitable for locking ot something, it would be good to lock a wheel to the frame (and use another U-lock to catch the other wheel and whatever you need to lock to).

Answer (score 4):

Also consider the [Master Lock Street Cuff](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0019RLL0G)s handcuff lock.

2 lengths available and works well. Comes with a water bottle cage mount for the frame.

[image]

Comment: I was going to make a comment on how the fame is not locked in this example, but then I realized that you would still need to to either cut or fold the rear wheel in order to steal the bike (neither of which are easy tasks). I like this technique.

Comment: Yep. I've been using this lock for years. It's been really good. Plus the WB cage mount keeps the weight low and balanced and out of the way.  The newer ones will fit around a 3" tire.

Comment: They don't seem very secure: http://www.wired.com/2011/01/pr_reviews_biketools_lock/